# How to insert a block from a drawing file into a current drawing using autolisp

Tags: lisp, autolisp

What I would like to do is insert specific blocks from a master file depending on user input. These blocks would then be moved around and combined to create a new block. Any help is appreciated.

I have searched online and have found a few examples of what I'm looking for but I can't seem to get anything working properly. My big question would be how do I tell it where the file is located.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this is some homework, could you provide exact instructions?

Comment: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/copy-block-definition-from-another-drawing-lisp-help/td-p/5519160 This seems to be a working version of what im looking for I just have no idea where to "plug in" the file and block information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution for adding a block to a drawing. I don't know what user inputs you expect to be acceptable and which are not, so I left a link to different commands that can be used. In addition, moving and combining blocks sounds a bit vague to me, but I think the solution for that will involve the `entsel` command.

I hope this helps you move towards the end goal you set out to accomplish.

```lisp
(defun C:AddBlock (/ sFile sStartPath)
    (setq sStartPath "P:\\ENG\\Blocks")
    
    ;; User Input capabilities
    ; https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-7F024C1B-EFB8-4F6C-9EFE-A6491210A4CD

    ;; User selects the file
    ;; https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-AD65DF88-5218-4655-B877-B4D33B9FB6D1
    (setq sFile (getfiled "Select Drawing as Block" sStartPath "dwg" 0))
    
    ;; Inserting the block
    (if (findfile sFile)(progn ;-----; https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-D671F67D-F92B-41FF-B9FA-A48EF52CF607
        (command "INSERTBLOCK" sFile); https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-1C989B35-2C5A-47EC-A0C9-71998EDFB157
    ));if<-progn

);C:AddBlock
```